# Generar random de un array string con preguntas de opción multiple (radio group) android studio

Tags: random, radiobutton, radiogroup

//Esto les lo que tengo en mi string xml

```
<resources>
<string name="app_name">MiAmigoTodaro1</string>
<string name="et_nombe">¿Cuál es tu nombre?</string>
<string name="boton">JUGAR</string>


<string name="et_vidas">Huesitos</string>
<string name="jugador_nombre">Jugador:</string>
<string name="total_score">Score: 0</string>
<string name="boton_sumar">Comprobar</string>
<string name="et_respuesta">Respuesta</string>
<string name="tv_pregunta">Pregunta</string>
<string name="button_check">Verifica</string>


<array name="todas_preguntas">
    <item>¿Cuál es el principal musculo inspiratorio?;Pectoral mayor;*Diafragma;Intercostal interno;Intercostal externo</item>
    <item>¿Rama terminal de la arteria carótida externa?;Art. lingual;Art. facial;Art. subclavia;*Art. maxilar</item>
    <item>Par craneal con componente funcional aferente somático;V;*II;III;IV</item>
    <item>dfkmkdfkndsnvl;k;II;*III;IV</item>
    <item>Nervio relacionado a extension del antebrazo;Cubital;*Radial;Musculocutaneo;Mediano</item>
    <item>Inerva el diafragma;Femoral;Mediano;;*Frénico</item>
</array>
```

//y esto es una parte de lo que tengo en mi main activity 2. tengo las alternativas agrupadas en un radio group. Cuando pulso el botón verificar pasa ala siguiente pregunta, pero en el mismo orden cada vez que ejecuto la aplicación.

```
public class Main2Activity_Nivel1 extends AppCompatActivity {

private TextView tv_nombre, tv_score;
private ImageView iv_huesitos;
private EditText et_respuesta;
private MediaPlayer mp, mp_baia_baia, mp_ohperdon;

private int ids_respuestas[] ={
        R.id.respuesta1, R.id.respuesta2, R.id.respuesta3, R.id.respuesta4
};


int score, resultado, huesitos = 3;
String nombre_jugador, string_score, string_huesitos;

private int respuesta_correcta;
private int pregunta_actual;
private String[] todas_preguntas;
private TextView tv_pregunta;
private RadioGroup group;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2__nivel1);


    Toast.makeText(this, "Nivel 1 - Cosas grandes", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    tv_nombre = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView_nombre);
    tv_score = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView_score);
    iv_huesitos = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView_vidas);

    nombre_jugador = getIntent().getStringExtra("jugador");
    tv_nombre.setText("Jugador: " + nombre_jugador);


    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);

    mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.goats);
    mp.start();
    mp.setLooping(true);

    mp_baia_baia = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.baia_baia);
    mp_ohperdon = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.ohperdon);




    tv_pregunta = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_pregunta);
    group = (RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.grupo_respuestas);
    Button button_check = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_check);
    todas_preguntas = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.todas_preguntas);
    pregunta_actual = 0;
    mostrarpregunta();



    // TODO: Cuando clickean al boton deberia pasar a la siguiente pregunta
    button_check.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            int id = group.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
            int respuesta = -1;
            for (int i = 0; i < ids_respuestas.length; i++) {
                if (ids_respuestas[i] == id) {
                    respuesta = i;
                }
            }
            if (respuesta == respuesta_correcta) {
                Toast.makeText(Main2Activity_Nivel1.this, "Muy bien!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                mp_baia_baia.start();
                score++;
                tv_score.setText("Score: " + score);

            } else{
                Toast.makeText(Main2Activity_Nivel1.this, "incorrecto", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                mp_ohperdon.start();
                huesitos--;

                switch (huesitos){
                    case 3:
                        iv_huesitos.setImageResource(R.drawable.craneo3);
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        iv_huesitos.setImageResource(R.drawable.craneo2);
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        iv_huesitos.setImageResource(R.drawable.craneo1);
                        break;
                    case 0:
                        Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), MainActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        finish();
                        mp.stop();
                        mp.release();

                        break;
                }

            }

            if (pregunta_actual < todas_preguntas.length-1){
                pregunta_actual++;
                mostrarpregunta();
            }
        }
    });
    // TODO: Molaria tener un boton que pase al anterior
}
private void mostrarpregunta() {
    String p = todas_preguntas[pregunta_actual];
    String[] partes = p.split(";");

    group.clearCheck();
    tv_pregunta.setText(partes[0]);
    for (int i = 0; i < ids_respuestas.length; i++){
        RadioButton rb = (RadioButton)findViewById(ids_respuestas[i]);
        String respuesta = partes[i+1];
        if(respuesta.charAt(0) == '*') {
            respuesta_correcta = i;
            respuesta = respuesta.substring(1);
        }
        rb.setText(respuesta);
    }
}
```

}

//Hasta ahora la aplicación me funciona sin problema, pero solo consigo pasar a la siguiente pregunta (pero siempre tengo el mismo orden de pregunta. Se que tengo que implementar el método random, pero no se en que parte ni como, agradecería la ayuda de la comunidad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La mejor forma quizás sea pasar ese `array` a una `List` y mezclar el contenido con `Collections.shuffle()`.

```
todas_preguntas = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.todas_preguntas);

// Creacion de List desde array
List<String> preguntasDesordenadas = Arrays.asList(todas_preguntas);
// Mezcla el contenido
Collections.shuffle(preguntasDesordenadas);
```

Ahora solo tendrias que cambiar el acceso al array como:

```
String p = todas_preguntas[pregunta_actual];
```

Por:

```
String p = preguntasDesordenadas.get(pregunta_actual);
```

Comment: Gracias Genio!! me funcionó :)